# jQuery trigger events attached to different delegated selectors?

Tags: javascript, triggers, jquery

Is it possible to avoid defining long function twice and just trigger already defined one that is attached to different delegated selectors with different events?

```
$('#list').on('click', 'li .controls a:nth-child(1)', function(event) {
    // many lines
});
```

^

```
$('#list').on('dblclick', 'li .title a', function(event) {
    // same set of lines
    // so just trigger the above function instead?
});
```

Comment: Note the different selectors + different events, same function content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare the function first

```
var handler = function(event) {
    // many lines
};
```

Then bind it multiple times to different delegate selectors

```
$('#list').on('click', 'li .controls a:nth-child(1)', handler);
$('#list').on('click', 'li .title a', handler);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a comma to add another selector to your event

```
$('#list').on('click', 'li .controls a:nth-child(1), li .title a', function(event) {
    // many lines                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is:

```
var handler = function(event) {
    // ...
};

$('#list').on('click', 'li .controls a:nth-child(1)', handler);
$('#list').on('click', 'li .title a', handler);
```

or just:

```
$('#list').on('click', 'li .controls a:nth-child(1), li .title a', function(event) {
    // ...
});
```